# How to use :include, :except, :only for hashes from :methods in rails render

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, render, rails-api

I need to render the itinerary json but **consolidating all todos** as a single json array nested inside:

```
render json: @itinerary, include: {
                           places: {
                             only: [:id, :title],
                             include: {
                               todos: {
                                  only: [:id, :content],
                                  include: :todo_type
                               },
                               place_category: {
                                  include: {
                                       todos: {
                                           only: [:id, :content],
                                           include: :todo_type
                                       }
                                  }
                               },
                               climate: {
                                   include: {
                                       todos: {
                                           only: [:id, :content],
                                           include: :todo_type
                                       }
                                   }
                               }
                             }
                           }
                         }
```

I wish to render all todos together, so that the client doesn't have to do the consolidate all todos, removing duplicates and doing other work on it.

So I created a method `consolidated_todos` in `place` model

```
def considated_todos
  todos = self.todos
  todos += self.place_category.todos
  todos += self.climate.todos
  todos
end
```

And then changed my render method to the following

```
render json: @itinerary, include: {
                           places: {
                             only: [:id, :title],
                             include: :place_category,
                             methods: [:consolidated_todos],
                           }
                         }
```

> How do I add `:include` *(:todo_type, etc.,)*, `:only` *(:id, :content, etc.,)* and `:except` **for hashes returned from `:methods`**?

I need to do something like  `methods: [ consolidated_todos: { include: :todo_type } ]`.

---

**EDIT**:

This question is **NOT** about

1. how to serialize resources
2. how to include nested resources
3. using jbuilder / Active Model Serializer / RABL / similar libs to do (1) or (2)

but is specifically about using `include` for hashes returned from `:methods` or an equivalent short workaround *(instead of using `as_json`)* for the same

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you can, and even you could, you probably should be creating different methods where you select data that you need and then them when you render the object. It will be easier to read and maintain.

Comment: `where you select data that you need and then them when you render the object`: can you add an example to make it even clear? _I didn't get your point_

Comment: Giving negatives to people trying to help you when you break rails best practices :/. You are probably still wondering why you don't get more responses.